# Python recognize two digit numbers as seperate numbers in my if statement?

Tags: python, function, numbers

When I run my code in here the numbers between (1,10) is no problem. But when I wrote for example 12 it returns Small, Medium instead of it should return Large. It seems like my statement doesn't recognize two digit numbers as a whole. How to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
answer = input("What's your number?")

print(answer)

for z in answer:
    
   if int(z) < 2:
        print('SMALL')
    elif int(z) < 10:
        print('MEDIUM')
    else:
        print('LARGE')
```

Comment: Hello, Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
And explain the errors you are getting in your attempt in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me that your loop is the cause. If you input 12 then answer="12". So when you say for z in answer you are effectively doing this:

```
for z in answer:
    print(z)
```

This will result in:

```
'1'
'2'
```

So to fix this you should get rid of the loop:

```
answer = input("What's your number?")

print(answer)
z = int(answer)

if z < 2:
    print('SMALL')
elif z < 10:
    print('MEDIUM')
else:
    print('LARGE')
```

Answer (score 0):

first answer is a string and when you put it in a loop you first get "1" and then "2". replace the loop to get correct answer

```
    answer = input("What's your number?")

  
   if int(answer) < 2:
        print('SMALL')
    elif int(answer) < 10:
        print('MEDIUM')
    else:
        print('LARGE')
```